# Vue3 typescript. How to get correct component type automatically

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

If I have a Vue3 component, HelloWorld like is

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
   {{name}}
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'hello'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setName(name: string): void {
      this.name = name
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

If I want to use this component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <hello-wrold ref="hello">
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import HelloWolrd from './hello-world'
export default defineComponent({
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$refs.hello.name) // ?
    this.$refs.hello.setName('stackoverflow') // ?
  }
})
</script>
```

typescript can not get correct type about HelloWorld component,what kind of type should i give?
I tryed this, can not work

```
  type Hello = typeof HelloWorld;
  (this.$refs.hello as Hello).name
```

or this, can not work too

```
  type Hello = InstanceType<typeof HelloWorld>;
  (this.$refs.hello as Hello).name

  type Hello2 = ComponentPublicInstance<typeof HelloWorld>;
  (this.$refs.hello as Hello).name
```

if i use this way，it can be work，but i think it is not a good idea, because it is not automatically

```
  type Hello = ComponentPublicInstance<unknown, unknown, { name: string }, ComputedOptions, {setName: (name: string) => void}>
  (this.$refs.hello as Hello).name // can work
```

So, what vue3 API or ts API should i use to get component type automatically?

Answer (score -1):

I know。。 InstanceType. it is work.
the problem is Vetur extend。